# c++ named parameter idiom - string property not set

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, idioms, named

Please consider the following (simple) code. The strange (?) behavior is in the `main()` routine and detailed below.

### data class

*Packet.h*

```
#include <string>

class Packet {
public:
    Packet(int iParam, std::string sParam);
    ~Packet();
    void setInt(int iParam);
    void setString(std::string sParam);

private:
    int iProperty_;
    std::string sProperty_;
};
```

*Packet.cpp*

```
#include "Packet.h"
using std::string;

Packet::Packet(int iParam, string sParam) : iProperty_(iParam), 
    sProperty_(sParam) {}
Packet::~Packet() {}

void Packet::setInt(int iParam) {
    iProperty_ = iParam;
}
void Packet::setString(std::string sParam) {
    sProperty_ = sParam;
}
```

### controller class

*PacketController.h*

```
#include <string>

class PacketController {
public:
    PacketController();
    ~PacketController();
    PacketController & andSetInt(int iParam);
    PacketController & andSetString(std::string sParam);

private:
    Packet packet_;
};
```

*PacketController.cpp*

```
#include "PacketController.h"
using std::string;

PacketController::PacketController() : packet_(0, "") {}
PacketController::~PacketController() {}

PacketController & PacketController::andSetInt(int iParam) {
    packet_.setInt(iParam);
    return *this;
}

PacketController & PacketController::andSetString(string sParam) {
    packet_.setString(sParam);
    return *this;
}
```

*main()*

```
int main() {
    PacketController& ctrlRef = PacketController()
        .andSetString("hello world")
        .andSetInt(19);

    PacketController ctrlVal = PacketController()
        .andSetString("hello world")
        .andSetInt(19);

    PacketController& ctrlRef2 = PacketController();
    ctrlRef2.andSetString("hello world")
        .andSetInt(19);

    return 0;
}
```

If execution is paused at the line `return 0;` of `main()` then the following values are seen on the internal `packet_` objects:

`ctrlRef - packet_:`  `iProperty_: 19`  **`sProperty_: ""`**

`ctrlVal - packet_:`  `iProperty_: 19`  `sProperty_: "hello world"`

`ctrlRef2 - packet_:`  `iProperty_: 19`  `sProperty_: "hello world"`

So why is `sProperty_` empty on the `packet_` object in `ctrlRef`? Is it something to do with the reference being seated on initialisation of the `PacketController` object? But then why is `iProperty_` on the `packet_` object of `ctrlRef` correctly set to `19`?

Comment: ymmv, but i think the named parameter idiom brings loads of boilerplate for little gain, you can have the names of the parameters appear on the call site if you simply use a `struct params { /*all params that you want to pass (with their names) */}` and make the constructor take a `params`

Comment: Your compiler should warn you about the code you show. If not then enable more warnings.

Comment: @1: had to look up 'ymmv'  :)  some example code? client code above is cool

Comment: @2: no warnings by default on Visual Studio and runtime execution doesn't appear to have any problem... (other than missing string)

Answer (score 0):

```
PacketController& ctrlRef = PacketController()
    .andSetString("hello world")
    .andSetInt(19);
```

`ctrlRef` is a reference to a temporary whose lifetime ended at the end of the full-expression evaluation (right at the `;`). The same can be said about `ctrlRef2`.

Using it results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/5470596).

On the other hand, `ctrlVal` is a value initialized from the temporary. Using it is fine.

Comment: [There are ways](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)... but resorting to a `std::unique` is probably best.

Comment: Thanks - useful link to GotW above. Worth noting that a reference to `const` can be bound to a temporary - although not much use above...